# Выполнить операцию без использования if и switch

Tags: java, if, switch

Поискал в интернете, как можно реализовать условие без использования if и switch, но так и не нашел, как это можно реализовать. Преподаватель видимо хочет, чтобы задача была решена необычным способом. Я так понимаю сокращенное условие freeShipping = (freeShipping == 0) ? true : false; также не подходит по условию задачи. Как это возможно реализовать иначе?

- создайте переменную freeShipping
- запишите без использования if или любых других условий:
- если shippingSum равно нулю, то freeShipping должна быть равна true, иначе freeShipping должна быть равна false

Comment: "freeShipping = (freeShipping == 0) ? true : false; также не подходит по условию задачи." --- почему такой вывод?

Comment: а возможно просто `freeShipping = (freeShipping == 0);` ?

Comment: а может даже вот так `freeShipping = !((bool)shippingSum);` (я давно джаву не трогал, возможно напильничком потыкать нужно

Comment: @KoVadim благодарю, это именно то, что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку переменная `freeShipping` булевского типа, то ей можно присвоить результат булевского выражения сравнения с 0:

```java
boolean freeShipping = shippingSum == 0;
```